# How is the context treated?

Tags: core-data

I have a weird behaviour on Core Data with my App. I have an App where user can create their own words entries with translation. When deleting all my Core Data I checked the nb of item and it was 0. When adding later 4 items the nb of items was 5?? I found the issue after a lot of tests and it seems not consistent for me: the issue was with this code:

```
fileprivate func duplicateCheckAndImport() {
    // Check for duplicates
    do {
        
        self.words = try context.fetch(Word.fetchRequest())   // grab all Words
        let nbOfWords = words!.count
        print ("The nb of words in duplicateCheck...: \(nbOfWords ?? 0)")
        
    }
        
    catch {
        // error message to add
    }

    let newWord = Word(context: self.context)

    do {
        self.words = try context.fetch(Word.fetchRequest())   // grab all Words
        let nbOfWords = words!.count
        print ("The nb of words in duplicateCheck...: \(nbOfWords ?? 0)")
        
    }
        
    catch {
        // error message to add
    }
```

the result of the 2 prints is 0 for the first grab and 1 for the 2nd grab which means that just this line of code -> let newWord = Word(context: self.context) adds an entry in Core Data but my purpose was just to take the context add words later on like this:

```
      let newWord = Word(context: self.context)
      newWord.name = item.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
      newWord.definition = item.definition.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you mention

```
let newWord = Word(context: self.context)
```

...creates a new instance. That's what `Word(context: self.context)` does-- it says, create a new instance of `Word` using the context that you pass in.

From the code you provide, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do that would not create a new instance. Your variable is called `newWord`, which suggests that you do mean to create a new `Word`, and that's what's happening.

Update: If you don't want the new instance, you can delete it just like any other managed object. So if you don't want `newWord`, you can

```
context.delete(newWord)
```

And then save changes. There are other ways to do this, but this is the simplest.

Comment: Ok thanks Tom! Yes I wanted to add newWord in CoreData and I asked user validation before saving it. If the user respond with no, how can I cancel this instance, I cannot find the right command as if I create a new entry he will add the old (canceled word) and new word?

Comment: @Dude1313 Updated